# Can I forward questions here from other SE sites?

Tags: support, migration

Questions relevant to proof assistants often get asked on other StackExchange sites. For example, the last such question I read was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70988226/). Can I import those questions to [PA](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com), both to establish whether they are on-topic, and to solicit more answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I forward questions here from other SE sites?

I tend to close and down vote lots of these questions but not all. If the person asking the question here is truly trying to learn, shows that they clearly understand the material and clearly shows why they are stuck or what they seek then I tend to treat them like any other question.

In other words asking such questions will require you to meet a higher standard. When done wrong they waste lots of time an effort, when done right they can help you.

---

The one example I know of that was a verbatim copy has already been closed and deleted. Thus I can not provide a link but the question posted on ProofAssistants was noted in this meta [question](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/q/84/5).

---

> to solicit more answers?

If that is your only reason then I will down vote and give the question a close vote. Use the bounty system on the current question.

If you seek more information then start a new question which you wrote from scratch and just reference the other question. Justify why you seek more answers. However seeking more answers seems like a list type question for which I also hold to a higher standard. Are they a point grab? If they are asked and made a wiki then they are not a point grab.

---

> establish whether they are on topic

If that is your only reason then do not do this, this again is a waste of time and effort. Write a new question from scratch.

---

Another thing you can do is ask a new question but then in the other question provide a link in the comment to your question. I do this often. The upside of this is that some search engines use links to judge the quality for inclusion in the search results. More links from quality places put the entry higher in the list.

There are other tricks but if I make them public I am doing myself a disservice.

Answer (score 4):

Only if they're on-topic and it's clearly marked at the top of your question that you've cross-posted it (with a link to the original question), and if the other site allows cross-site duplicates. If an answer is received on either site, it's good practice to mark the other site's version of the question accordingly. This saves people time and energy.

Answer (score 3):

This is covered by [this post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/208518), but the general rule is that **you should not cross-post questions across multiple sites on the network.**